# Code within page.evaluate() is not working

Tags: javascript, dom, puppeteer, console.log

I want to **automate login and get text data from PowerBI website using puppeteer**. I am able to automate Login successfully but, the **code within page.evaluate is not working**(it contains the code for getting text data from website) Here's the code.

```
  col_headers=[] 
  await page2.evaluate(() => {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("columnHeaders");
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    col_headers = elements[i].innerText;
  }});
  console.log(col_headers)
```

NOTE:
1)I tried adding **console.log** into the function to check if control is going within it. But, It is **not getting executed** either.
2) If I **don't enclose** the code within **page.evaluate**, the code throws *"document not available"* error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should not mix the code from browser and Node.js (puppeteer) context. Currently, variable `col_headers` is declared in Node.js (puppeteer) context, while code to populate it is in the browser context.
2. `console.log` inside `page.evaluate()` callback is executed in browser context, so the data is logged in browser console (in DevTools).

Try this:

```js
  const col_headers = await page2.evaluate(() => {
    const headers = [];
    const elements = document.getElementsByClassName("columnHeaders");
    for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      headers.push(elements[i].innerText);
    }
    return headers;
  });
    
  console.log(col_headers)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the innerText to the end of the `col_headers` array, currently you are over-writing the entire array each time.

i.e. instead of

```
col_headers = elements[i].innerText;
```

you should put

```
col_headers.push(elements[i].innerText);
```

Comment: Thankyou very much for pointing this out. But, the control doesn't go within page.evaluate function itself.